# Data labels inside the slice of piecharts - Google Charts api

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, pie-chart, google-pie-chart

I am trying to generate an < img src > tag for including in an email report, for which I am using Google charts api to generate an image using the following URL.

I have my URL something like this:

https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?cht=pc&chco=f6c23e%2Cae7f06%2Cffdf8d&chd=t:60,7,167&chs=275x100&chl=High(25.6%)%7CMedium(3.0%)%7CLow(71.4%)

The challenge is that I need to show the percentage numbers marked in brackets inside the slices   of pie-charts [25.6% , 3.0%, 71.4%].

Kindly let me know if there is any attribute or parameter which allows to do that.
Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: there is not an option listed in the docs, have you considered using the current version of google charts, rather than the deprecated image charts library? you can generate an image with the new version, which has more options for labels...

Comment: @WhiteHat Thank you for your reply. Yes there is something called the image-charts (https://documentation.image-charts.com/pie-charts/) , in which we have an option for labels to be placed inside pie chart. However the watermark is something I don't want to display here. It comes along with free version anyway.